# How do I exclude top and bottom 5% of annual salary on 18 million records in TSQL, then use the seleced data to calculate average

Tags: sql, t-sql, bigdata

I have 18 million rows in a column (income), and i would like to exclude the top & bottom 5% of the income to calculate a more accurate average on income.

Comment: Calculate  [PERCENT_RANK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213573%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), narrow data and calculate AVG.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any data about structure, grouping and so on. So this is proof of concept.
Calculate [PERCENT_RANK()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213573%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), narrow data, calculate Average.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e295b/17)**

```
/* Preparing data */
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), income INT)

;WITH Nums(Number) AS
(SELECT 1 AS Number
  UNION ALL
 SELECT Number+1 FROM Nums where Number<100   /* Warn here recursive CTE */
)
INSERT INTO tab(income)
SELECT Number FROM Nums;


/* Main query */
WITH cte(id, income, [percent]) AS
(
  SELECT 
       id
      ,income
      ,[percent] = PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY income)
  FROM tab
)
SELECT [average_income] =  AVG(income)
FROM cte
WHERE 
   [percent] > 0.05 
   AND [percent] < 0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with top5 as 
(select top 5 percent income from tablename)
, bottom5 as
(select top 5 percent income from tablename order by income desc)
select avg(income)
from tablename
where income not in (select income from top5 union all select income from bottom5)
```

You can do this by calculating top 5 and bottom 5 percent and then excluding them from the final calculation using `not in`.

Comment: NOT IN will exclude values from the middle 90% that aren't distinct from the other 10%, changing the "average."

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  `Percentile_rank()` *might* be the way to go.  However, the following may be faster:

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select max(salary) as maxs
      from (select top 5 percent salary
            from table t
            order by salary
           ) t
     ) m1 cross join
     (select min(salary) as mins
      from (select top 5 percent salary
            from table t
            order by salary desc
           )
    ) m2
where s.salary >= mins and s.salary <= maxs;
```

The idea is that the subqueries for the min and max can use an index, effectively, to get the 5% and 95% values.  The rest of the query would then just be a full table scan.

Comment: Many income values could fall on the lines so you can't use their values as the filter. You have to count out 5% of the rows.

Comment: @TomBlodget . . . I'm confused.  You are not the OP so how do you know what the data looks like.

Comment: The question gives a general problem. If this answer is optimized for a more specific one, just say so.